# How to refresh powerBI XMLA endpoint dataset using with system managed Identity

Tags: azure, powershell, powerbi

In azure automation account we used below powershell script to refresh powerbi dataset using run as account. but now Microsoft retired this feature and we need to migrate using system identity.  Can anyone help us how we can migrate below code using  system identity to refresh powerbi dataset?

```
$servicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name "runasAccount" 
Invoke-ProcessASDatabase -ServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $ServicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId -CertificateThumbprint $ServicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint -TenantId $ServicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
                                        -server $pbiInstanceName `
                                        -DatabaseName $pbiModelName `
                                        -RefreshType DataOnly `
```

Comment: Microsoft is slowly transitioning from Windows Credentials to OAUTH 2.0 because OAUTH 2.0 will work in Windows, MAC, and Linux.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization